# Can negative absolute temperature be achieved?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, temperature

Thermodynamics does not allow the attainment of the absolute zero of temperature. Is then the term "negative temperature" a misnomer?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21851/2451 and links therein.

Comment: [Sixty Symbols on negative temperatures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yTeBUpR17Rw).

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Thanks for the link. I found two references mentioned there to be quite useful. Here are the links https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.0545   and  https://journals.aps.org/pr/abstract/10.1103/PhysRev.103.20

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Your question seems to be predicated on the idea that [negative absolute temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_temperature) is somehow supposed to be "colder" than absolute zero, and you are right that that would be non-sensical.

But actually, in a very precise sense, negative absolute temperatures are *hotter* than all positive temperatures, see also [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/21851/50583). This is simply a result of the statistical definition of temperature $T$, which is
$$ \frac{1}{T} = \frac{\partial S}{\partial E},$$
where $S$ is the entropy of the system and $E$ its energy content, so $\beta := \frac{1}{T}$ is actually the more natural quantity to think about in the physical formalism. See also [this excellent answer by DanielSank](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/231065/50583) for how the $\frac{1}{T}$ appears naturally as a Lagrange multiplier in thermodynamics.

From the above, we see that temperature is negative for system whose entropy *decreases* as the energy rises. Such systems are unusual, but they are not forbidden. Absolute zero, $T\to 0$, corresponds to $\beta \to \infty$. As the system gets hotter, $\beta$ decreases. $\beta\to 0$ looks weird in terms of temperature, since it corresponds to $T\to \infty$, but since it is $\beta$ that is of primary physical importance, it is not actually forbidden for it to cross zero and become negative. In terms of temperature, a system crossing the $\beta = 0$ point would have to be described as heating up all the way to "infinite positive temperature", then *flipping the sign of the temperature* and starting to go towards $T= 0$ again from $-\infty$.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on ACuriousMind's post, consider as a toy model a system with $2$ energy levels, say $0$ and $E>0$. These have respective probabilities $(1+e^{-\beta E})^{-1},\,e^{-\beta E}(1+e^{-\beta E})^{-1}$, so the mean energy is $E(1+e^{\beta E})^{-1}$. Clearly, this is $0$ at $\beta=+\infty$ ($T=0^+$), $E/2$ at $\beta=0$ ($T=\infty$) and $E$ at $\beta=-\infty$ ($T=0^-$), so a large negative $T$ is especially hot as measured by mean energy.

It turns out $2$-level systems cannot reach $\beta < 0$ while in thermal equilibrium. Lasers work by maintaining negative $T$ in systems with at least $3$ levels (well, [most do](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasing_without_inversion)). Thus the highest energy level is the most occupied. This is an example of [population inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Population_inversion#Creating_a_population_inversion).

Comment: I like your answer except your argument is based on Boltzmann distribution which is valid only when the system is in equilibrium.

Comment: @mithusengupta123 If you have a preferred definition of temperature that works in non-equilibrium dynamics, you can work out which microstates have negative temperatures. As lasers prove, negative temperatures are certainly possible at least in equilibrium.

Comment: Could it be that you did an odd number of sign  mistakes here? For example, in the probabilities, it should be $(1+e^{-\beta E})^{-1}$ and $e^{-\beta E} (1+e^{-\beta E})^{-1}$, respectively. Only then your statements make sense.