# Regarding the Boltzmann entropy formula, is the Boltzmann constant really arbitrary?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, kinetic-theory, physical-constants

In the top answer to this question ([Is the Boltzmann constant really that important?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/231017/is-the-boltzmann-constant-really-that-important/231065)) I read that **the Boltzmann constant is just a dummy factor which converts energy to temperature**.

But that allows me to put another numerical value in place of the Boltzmann constant but keep the dimension J/K.

I.e. what if, in
$$S=c\ln W,$$
I put $c=56  \, \mathrm J/\mathrm K$ in place of $c=k\approx 1.38\cdot 10^{-23} \,  \mathrm J/\mathrm K$?

On the page [Thermodynamic beta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_beta), the Boltzmann entropy using the Boltzmann constant implies thermodynamic beta, which implies (according to [Derivation of Boltzmann Distribution Law](https://bouman.chem.georgetown.edu/S98/boltzmann/boltzmann.htm)) the Boltzmann distribution.

So the Boltzmann distribution depends on the numerical value of Boltzmann constant. Then why is the Boltzmann constant just a dummy factor?

For example, the mean speed of molecules depends on

$$S=k\ln W.$$

**Changing the numerical value of $k$ would make the speed totally different.**

Comment: Guessing but the definition of temperature probably depends on the arbitrary value of the Boltzmann constant. If this dependence is as $\textbf{K} \cdot k_B = $const. (in Joules) his would make the temperature dependent terms invariant under arbitrary constant selection.

Comment: Re **Changing the numerical value of $k$  would make the speed totally different**: In the expression $S = k\,\ln\Omega$, the $S$ on the left hand side has nothing to do with speed. That $S$ instead represents entropy, which has units of energy/temperature.

Answer (score 3):

In thermodynamics, the temperature is actually defined in terms of the entropy:

$\frac{1}{T} = \left(\frac{\partial S}{\partial U} \right)_{V,N}$.

Therefore, if you would change the definition of the bolzmann constant to $k' = a k$, the temperature would scale accordingly with a factor $1/a$, and the combination $kT$, which appears in the Boltzmann distribution, would remain the same.