# Would setting the ideal gas constant to $1$ yield an attractive natural temperature scale?

Tags: temperature, units, ideal-gas, dimensional-analysis, absolute-units

In this recent [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/485037/why-is-the-length-of-the-kelvin-unit-of-temperature-equal-to-that-of-the-celsius), there was a comment 'The "zero point" of Kelvin is natural, but the scale is not'.  This led me to wonder whether setting $R = 1$ in the ideal gas law would be an attractive and more natural temperature scale.

I am aware that changing to such a scale is not practical, the investment in the Kelvin is too great.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [natural units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_units) Boltzmann's constant, $k$, is normally set to one, rather than $R$. They differ by a factor of Avogadro's number; a mole is an arbitrarily defined unit based on the kilogram and is not "natural".

At least in my experience of high energy physics choosing $k = 1$ is common practice; I'm sure it occurs in other branches too.

Comment: Plus one for beating me to the post by 35 seconds.

Comment: Regarding your edit, there are several different systems of natural units. All but one sets $k_b$ to one. The one that doesn't? Its sole concern is gravitation, so it only sets $c$ and $G$ to one.

Answer (score 1):

> Would setting the ideal gas constant to 1 yield an attractive natural temperature scale?

Not really. The universal gas constant involves two arbitrary units: energy and temperature, and also the unitless mole. Getting rid of the concept of moles results in Boltzmann's constant $k_b$. This is the value that is set to 1 rather than $R$ in all systems of natural units.